# How to convert string "HH:MM" to timestamp using moment js

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs

I want to get the time difference between

`2018-02-24T00:45:00.000+0000` and `"08:00"`

`"08:00"` is an hour and minute, and since it is a string I have to convert `"08:00"` to a timestamp using `momentjs.`

Comment: `my first move is to convert "08:00" to a timestamp using momentjs` - ok, show your first move

Comment: That is my question. How to convert it to timestamp using momentjs.

Comment: .valueOf() converts to timestamp. but moment deprecated HH:mm setters, you'll have to provide a date. you can get today date, or your other date or another you would like

Comment: Oh. So your first move is actually to ask someone to write it for you on stack overflow

Comment: @JaromandaX dude your comments on questions is pure gold

Comment: @guijob, Thanks for the idea. I just have to use the date of the first timestamp and concatenate it to "08:00".

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
var m1 = moment('2018-02-24T00:45:00.000+0000');
var splitDate2 = "08:00".split(':');
var m2 = moment('2018-02-24T00:45:00.000+0000').set({'hour': splitDate2[0], 'minute': splitDate2[1]})

m1.diff(m2, 'ms') // diff in milliseconds
```